# Eclipse autocomplete not working on one file but working on other file

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

The autocomplete of eclipse is **not working on one file of project but working on other java files of same project** and I searched for hours but I couldn't find an answer to solve it.

In my workspace there are 6 projects and autocomplete is working fine in all the projects and theirs files but autocomplete is not working on one file of the project.

**I already done with the following solutions**

1. restoring the default options in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced'
2. No Hijacked of Ctrl+Space key combination
3. Regional and Language Options set to US(English)

But still problem is still exist in that file only. Help me out of this issue!

> **I just re-check my file again then i found that if was not working in particular if condition otherwise it was working on whole file. So can you suggest me why is should happens ?**

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Can you show your code where you are expecting autocomplete to work?

Comment: This is one specific case where a screenshot would be helpful. (In particular, it's possible that the wrong editor is attached to that file.)

Comment: you can checkout the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with main.cpp file in C++ project. I could fix it by deleting main.cpp and creating it with Eclipce panel. "New"->"Source file"